# Spark with Ignite - Application keeps running

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I'm trying to write/read from/to Ignite in a Spark application. Both reading and writing seems to work fine, but the application doesn't end even if it finishes what it had to do.

In particular the log keeps printing the same lines:

```
2018-10-23 09:08:12 DEBUG GridCachePartitionExchangeManager:558 - Before waiting for exchange futures [futs[], worker=GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=215498915, interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#35]]
2018-10-23 09:08:12 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=2374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285692400, period=2000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$13@2e49ebc1], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:14 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=3374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285694375, period=3000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2@579e2347], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:14 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=2374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285694400, period=2000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$13@2e49ebc1], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:14 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=4374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285694437, period=3000, cancel=false, task=MetricsUpdater [prevGcTime=337, prevCpuTime=16515, super=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager$MetricsUpdater@1fad637f]], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:15 DEBUG TcpCommunicationSpi:558 - Balancing data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1]
2018-10-23 09:08:16 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=1374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285696182, period=10000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$12@1c86b2f2], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:16 DEBUG ClientListenerProcessor:558 - Balancing data [min0=0, minIdx=0, max0=-1, maxIdx=-1]
2018-10-23 09:08:16 DEBUG GridTimeoutProcessor:558 - Timeout has occurred [obj=CancelableTask [id=2374d20a661-967c7da2-84ed-46d9-9ec1-fd64ab02e16a, endTime=1540285696405, period=2000, cancel=false, task=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing$13@2e49ebc1], process=true]
2018-10-23 09:08:17 DEBUG GridCachePartitionExchangeManager:558 - Before waiting for exchange futures [futs[], worker=GridWorker [name=partition-exchanger, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=215498915, interrupted=false, runner=exchange-worker-#35]]
```

and so on.

Every now and then it also prints:

```
2018-10-23 09:07:59 INFO  IgniteKernal:566 - 
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=a7f30542, uptime=00:01:00.019]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=2, nodes=4, CPUs=4]
    ^-- CPU [cur=1.67%, avg=9.47%, GC=0%]
    ^-- PageMemory [pages=0]
    ^-- Heap [used=278MB, free=69.36%, comm=478MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=129MB, free=-1%, comm=130MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=4, qSize=0]
```

I'm just doing very simple reading/writing operations on Ignite, and when I'm configuring the reader/writer with

```
.option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE, path)
```

the `path` corresponds to a this configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
                       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
                         <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite native persistence. -->
                         <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                             <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                                 <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                               </bean>
                             </property>
                           </bean>
                         </property>
                       </bean>
</beans>
```

**UPDATE:**

The setup is the following. I'm currently using Vagrant + Ansible + VirtualBox to run three machines. The first one runs spark master and the others run spark workers. Ignite is configured on all machines, but it is run using the `ignite.sh` script only on the workers. It is configured with persistency enabled, so the cluster is also activated by issuing `control.sh --activate`.

Everything is working fine and I can event query the data using the REST api, the only thing that seems to not work is this thing of keeping the application running.

**UPDATE 2:**

The suggestion of @StephenDarlington partially worked. Closing the Spark context at the end of the application, makes the executor finish the task. On the other hand from the UI I can now see that 0 applications are running, but the driver is still in running state.

Here's the stdout of the driver program:

```
2018-10-26 11:05:37 DEBUG G:558 - Ignite instance stopped ok: null
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  StandaloneSchedulerBackend:54 - Shutting down all executors
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:54 - Asking each executor to shut down
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint:54 - MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  BlockManagerMaster:54 - BlockManagerMaster stopped
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:54 - OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
2018-10-26 11:05:37 INFO  SparkContext:54 - Successfully stopped SparkContext
2018-10-26 11:05:39 DEBUG PoolThreadCache:81 - Freed 25 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: shuffle-server-7-2
2018-10-26 11:05:39 DEBUG PoolThreadCache:81 - Freed 31 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: rpc-server-5-1
2018-10-26 11:05:39 DEBUG PoolThreadCache:81 - Freed 4 thread-local buffer(s) from thread: rpc-server-5-2
```

Comment: Do you close the Spark connection once you're finished? (The debug statements don't look good, but I'm not sure they're relevant to your problem here. The metrics are... just that.)

Comment: The debug logs actually seem OK. "Timeout has occurred" here means that specified amount of time has passed and a repating task (such as metrics logging or SQL processor cleanup) is going to be executed. So, all these logs just mean that the node is up and running.

Comment: How do you start Ignite? In other words, which type of deployment/Spark integration do you use? Is standalone or embedded (see [this link](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/installation-deployment) for details)

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov please see the update.

Comment: @StephenDarlington Actually your solution partially worked. By stopping the spark context, the application goes into the FINISHED state. The problem is that the driver remains in RUNNING state.

Answer (score 0):

## How does (not) Spark manage Ignite servers

So, you're running Ignite integration with Spark in [Standalone mode](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/installation-deployment#section-standalone-deployment).

In this mode Ignite nodes run independently from Spark, Spark doesn't contol Ignite's lifecycle. Compare it to any other database - applications don't start and stop MySQL themselves, MySQL runs on its own.

For the sake of illustration, compare it to the [embedded mode](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/installation-deployment#embedded-deployment) (**DO NOT use that mode, it is deprecated and will eventually be removed**). In that Spark starts Ignite servers itself in each worker, and stops them when it's done. It's somewhat (although not completely) similar to an application running with SQLite - there is no SQLite server running outside of the application and managed separately.

## How to shutdown Ignite cluster manually

If you want to kill Ignite nodes when you're done with Spark, you have to do it yourself. There are several options.

### Using `kill`

Yep, just that, good old `kill <pid>`. Better not to use `kill -9` to allow Ignite to catch the signal and perform some cleanup, although it should start even after `kill -9` given that your `walMode` is `FSYNC` or `LOG_ONLY`.

You could somehow trigger the `kill` from your Spark application during its shutdown.

### Using `Ignition::stop` and `IgniteCompute`

There is a trick you can use to kill a remote node via Java code.

`Ignition::stop` method stops a local Ignite node. You can execute that on every node remotely via `IgniteCompute`. Just remember to spawn a new thread from the task you're sending - trying to stop Ignite from a the task itself is a bad idea.

The code would look roughly like this (not tested!):

```
// Start a client node. Pass an appropriate configuration to connect to the cluster.
Ignition.setClientMode(true);
Ignite clusterKiller = Ignition.start();

// Stop all remote nodes.
clusterKiller.compute(clusterKiller.cluster().forRemotes()).broadcast(() -> {
    // Use a new thread to avoid deadlock.
    new Thread(() -> {
        Ignition.stop(false);
    }).start();
});

// Stop the client node.
clusterKiller.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Anyway just because Ignite is run independently from Spark I don't understand it seems that it prevents the Spark application from finishing. I didn't modify the `SPARK_CLASSPATH` in `spark-env.sh` as AFAIK it is deprecated. What I've done is to modify the classpath through `spark.driver.extraClassPath` and `spark.executor.extraClassPath` in `spark-defaults.conf.j2`.

Comment: Another weird thing is that from the spark driver log I can also see the Ignite logo (the one that appears when it is started with the `ignite.sh` script). Does this means that it is being started by spark as in embedded mode? And maybe it is'nt actually using the already started one? Another thing that makes me think this is that initially I had a permission error as the spark user was trying to write in the `$IGNITE_HOME/work` directory and I had to create a common group for spark and ignite user and set write permission for that group.